# Hang on wait_for_server() on import, but not direct use

Tags: python, actionlib

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a function called gripper.py with the lines

```
grip_r_client = actionlib.SimpleActionClient('r_gripper_controller/gripper_action', Pr2GripperCommandAction)
print "waiting for right gripper server"
grip_r_client.wait_for_server()
```

Then I have a script, test_gripper.py. If I try to `import gripper.py`, the program gets stuck at wait_for_server(). On the other hand, if I just copy those lines into test_gripper.py, or if I do `execfile('gripper.py')`, it works.

What's going on?

Edit: here's the full code. I would upload the package, but I don't have enough karma.

gripper.py:

```
import roslib
roslib.load_manifest('test')
import rospy, actionlib
from pr2_controllers_msgs.msg import Pr2GripperCommandAction
grip_r_client = actionlib.SimpleActionClient('r_gripper_controller/gripper_action',Pr2GripperCommandAction)
print "waiting for right gripper server"
grip_r_client.wait_for_server()
```

test_gripper.py:

```
import roslib
roslib.load_manifest('test')
import rospy,actionlib
rospy.init_node('test_gripper') 
import gripper
# OR ...
#execfile("gripper.py")
```

I realize this is non-idiomatic code, and it's really easy to fix the problem (I create a Gripper class, and wait_for_server in its **init** method), but it's a strange phenomenon.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10732/hang-on-wait_for_server()-on-import,-but-not-direct-use/) by [joschu](https://answers.ros.org/users/896/joschu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 131 on 2011-07-26

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In order for wait_for_server to work, ROS has to be initialized. When you `import gripper.py`, python tries to run the 3 lines you pasted above since, I assume, they're not contained within any kind of function. So, if you're doing the import at the top of the file before a call to `rospy.init_node` the `wait_for_server` call will never return.

Normally, you'd wrap those three lines up in a function, import the file, and then call the function later after a call to `rospy.init_node`.

I'll admit that I'm guessing on a lot of the points I made since there's not enough information to be sure what's happening in the original post, but hopefully this helps.

---

Originally posted by [eitan](https://answers.ros.org/users/107/eitan/) with karma: 2743 on 2011-07-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tpratkanis_wg](https://answers.ros.org/users/927/tpratkanis_wg/) on 2011-09-02**:
I think you are missing a rospy.init_node(...)

**Comment by [joschu](https://answers.ros.org/users/896/joschu/) on 2011-07-28**:
Nope, I did initialize the node before the import. I edited my post to give more detail.